# Firebase data not displayed on screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a project in react native in which I have to retrieve data from firebase and display it in the form of Cards in the application. The data is retrieved and stored in the array(I have checked using alert and log). But when I try to map it to the render function. Nothing happens. No error.

```
        constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
        items:[]
    }

    ref = firebase.database().ref("users/").orderByKey();


    }


          componentWillMount()
    {
        ref.on("value",(snapshot) => {

            const itemss=[];
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {

                var userkey = childSnapshot.key;
                var userdata = childSnapshot.val();
                itemss.push({
                    key:userkey,
                    ite:childSnapshot.val().ite,
                });


                });
                 this.setState({
                    items:itemss,
                });


            });


        }
```

I think it might be a problem with async data collection from firebase but I am still unable to get this working. The code to show how it is displayed is:

```
     <View>
                {
                    this.state.items.map(function (i) {
                        return(
                            <View onPress={alert(i)} style= 
               {{marginLeft:100,height:50,
               width:150,backgroundColor:'red'}}>

             <Text style={{fontSize:50,color:'#000'}}>{i.ite}</Text>
                            </View>
                        );

                    })

                }
            </View>
```

Kindly tell me what am I missing in the above code.

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: Also you need to do: `this.setState({
                    items:itemss,
                });` outside of the `forEach` loop.

Comment: I have added the code for constructor where the state is set. I will check "outside of the forEach loop" and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Now there is an error saying that `it.item` is an undefined object

Comment: Update your code, or make a CodeSandbox example.

Comment: I have updated the code. Kindly check what could be the possible problem.